# IPython split screen

Tags: vim, ipython

Is there some way to vertically split the screen in IPython so that I can see my code and the interpreter simultaneously? I'm using Vim for editing. Right now, I use two terminal tabs - one for Vim and the other for IPython.

Thanks!

Comment: what OS? Windows, OSX, linux?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). And I use gnome-terminal for working.

Comment: Don't think you can with normal gnome terminal, but you should try terminator https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/

Comment: Cool! It's not what I expected, but still does the trick. Could you reply to my original question so that I can mark it as answered? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, gnome should really include that natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with tmux (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)

With tmux's default configuration, run tmux, then you can vertical split using `ctrl-b %`. You can move between left and right side with `ctrl-b <arrow>`.

You can also do much more with it, such as horizontal split (`ctrl-b "`), start a terminal in a tab (`ctrl-b c`), attach your existing tmux session from another computer (`$ tmux attach`)...

It can be tweaked to use gnu screen's keyboard shortcuts (with prefix `ctrl-a`). You can also enable mouse support to switch panes, resize them, swich tab (see http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/07/16/tmux-and-mouse-mode/).

Comment: You're right, I was a bit misusing the `<kbd>` tag, should be better now :)

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't make these sarcastic comments, but you took it in good spirits, phew ... personally I refer to [this handy table](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1950) for how to use `<kbd>` tags. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IPython with ZeroMQ enabled, take a look at [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) (I'm the author, but it ships with IPython)

Using this plugin, you can send lines or whole files for IPython to execute, and also get back object introspection and word completions
 in Vim, like what you get with: `object?<enter>` and `object.<tab>` in IPython. If you use gVim, you'll also get object docstring tooltips when you hover over the text (see the screencast mentioned below).

Take a look at two screencasts of this plugin in action on [this post](http://pirsquared.org/blog/vim-ipython.html). Don't worry about the connection string looking different, that's just the way it was back in IPython 0.11.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the plugin ConqueShell (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771)

Start an ipython interpreter in split mode:

vertical split:

```
:ConqueTermVSplit ipython
```

however, I found a horizontal split easier to use:

```
:ConqueTermSplit ipython
```

You can switch windows as you normally would in VIM by `C-w-j` `C-w-k` etc.
Text selections can be sent to the ConqueShell window by pressing F9 (default key binding, of course you can change this).

As an example of how it looks (ipython to the right in v-split, a bash shell in the bottom left):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFxss.png (I can't include images directly due to lack of reputation)

Comment: Thanks! Although the other answers are also very good, I suppose this is what I was originally expecting. This is exactly what I'm doing with terminator now.